# Plane Geometry $n^n$ construction

Tags: geometry

Given a line segment of length $n$. how to construct $$n^n, n \in N$$ using straight edge and compass
**Example:-** given line segment's of length **a** and **b**. i can construct $$\sqrt{\mathbf a^2 + \mathbf b^2}$$ by drawing line segment **a** with straight edge and drawing line segment **b** perpendicular to line segment **a** at one end. then joining the other end's of line segment **a** and **b** we get the desired result. 

Regards,
vishal

Comment: As $n$ is a natural number, $n^n$ is just a multiple of $n$ and can be constructed by doing $n$ $n^{n-1}$ times.

Comment: @Gerry ... or just doing "1" $n^n$ times. :)

Comment: @Blue, I chose not to assume that $1$ is available.

Comment: @Gerry Whoops ... I missed that the given length was $n$.

Answer (score 2):

While not a straightedge-and-compass procedure, and though providing only a fraction of the length sought, there's a way to "construct" $n^n/n!$ geometrically in the plane in just $n$ simple steps.

Identify a point $P_1$ on a unit circle. Anchor the segment of length $n$ at $P_1$, and then wrap the segment about the circle, reaching a point $P$. Starting at $P$, "peel back" curve $PP_1$ to determine its [involute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute), $PP_2$. Then, again starting at $P$, peel back curve $PP_2$ to determine *its* involute, $PP_3$; continue until you reach involute $PP_n$ of curve $PP_{n-1}$.

Throughout the process, $|PP_i| = \frac{1}{n!} n^i$, so that $PP_n$ has the length promised.

(For length $n^n$ itself, you could take one more step to create $PP_{n+1}$ as the involute of curve $PP_n$. Then *segment* $P_n P_{n+1}$ has length $n^n/n!$, and you can just make $n!$ copies of that.)

---

The more-general result ---that starting with a circular arc $PP_1$ of length $\theta$ gives rise to involutes of length $\theta^i/i!$ for $\theta$ not-necessarily an integer--- is the foundation of Y. S. Chaikovsky's revelation of the geometry of the power series of sine and cosine. (See my Bloog post, ["The Geometry of the Power Series for Trig Functions"](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/the-geometry-of-the-power-series-for-trig-functions/).)

Comment: vishal, I don't understand why you ask for a straight-edge and compass construction of some length, and then accept an answer that isn't a straight-edge and compass construction, and gives a different length?

Comment: yes problem is still not solved using straight edge and compass. Got excited to see the information shared by @Blue. will be reverting my acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a path to $n^n$ exactly, via legitimate straightedge-and-compass constructions. (Hereafter, "construct" means "construct with straightedge and compass".)

If you have a segment of length $n$, then you can construct a segment of length $1$, and therefore also a right triangle $\triangle P_0OP_1$ with legs $|OP_i| = n^i$. For each $1 \le i \le n-1$, construct line $p_i$ perpendicular to $P_{i-1}P_i$ at $P_i$, and let $P_{i+1}$ be the point where $p_i$ meets ray $\overrightarrow{P_{i-1}O}$; then $\triangle P_iOP_{i+1}$ is a right triangle (with right angle at $O$) similar to $\triangle P_{i-1}OP_{i}$ (and thus is also ultimately similar to $\triangle P_0OP_1$).

The resulting chain of similar triangles yields this chain of proportions:

$$n = \frac{|OP_1|}{|OP_0|} = \frac{|OP_2|}{|OP_1|} = \cdots = \frac{|OP_{i+1}|}{|OP_i|}= \cdots = \frac{|OP_n|}{|OP_{n-1}|}$$

whence $|OP_i| = n^i$ for all $i$, including $i=n$.